# is there a cruise control style 'green light' taskbar monitor for tfs?

Tags: tfs, build-automation, cruisecontrol

We used to have Cruise Control and have recently moved to TFS - I miss the green light letting me know everything was fine!  I just missed a build failed email and got latest :(

Is there a green light task bar app for TFS?  I googled it but just found some USB light one - which does look good, but the lights are pricey.

Cheers,

Andy

Comment: I don't know about a green light for TFS... But a good solution is to go back to cc :-)

Comment: as someone probably moving to Team Build with the release of 2010, I to am interested in this.

Comment: I used CruiseControl with TFS, that is one option.

Comment: TeamCity comes with one, and that integrates with TFS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are after a replacement to the cctray application in CruiseControl then take a look at the [Build Notification Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx) that comes in the TFS Power Tools in TFS 2008 and installed as standard in VS2010.